# Do the terms of an iid sequence whose law has infinite expected value necessarily exceed the partial sums of the sequence infinitely often?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(0,\infty)$, and let $(\mathbf X_n)_1^\infty$ be a sequence of independent $\mu$-distributed random variables. Fix $\kappa > 0$, and consider

A) $\int x \; d\mu(x) = \infty$

B) There almost surely exist infinitely many $n$ such that
$$
\mathbf X_{n + 1} > \kappa \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbf X_i.
$$

Then (B) implies (A) (this follows from the law of large numbers together with the Borel-Cantelli lemma.) My question is: does (A) imply (B)?

According to the generalized Borel-Cantelli lemma, condition (B) is equivalent to

B$'$) The series
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu\left(\left(\kappa\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbf X_i,\infty\right)\right)
$$
diverges almost surely. This fact was [used](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=402890) to show that (B) holds when $d\mu(x) \sim x^{-(1 + \varepsilon)} dx$ ($\varepsilon\in (0,1)$.) I can also use it to show that (B) holds when $d\mu(x) \sim 1/(x^2\log(x))$, $d\mu(x) \sim 1/(x^2\log(x)\log\log(x))$, etc., using complicated calculations. This is highly suggestive that the result holds in general...

Comment: Your title seems to ask whether A implies B, but your question is whether B implies A?

Comment: Right - so I'm not sure about the question either. If $(X_n)$ is a sequence of positive iid random variables, if $\alpha<\mathbb EX_1$, we a.s. have $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i>n\alpha$ for all large $n$. The SLLN also implies $X_{n+1}<\alpha n$ for large $n$, so that if $\mathbb EX_1<\infty$, then B does not hold. You explained why B does hold if the expectation is infinite, so we're done, right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got the order of implication confused. I know (B) implies (A) and want to know whether (A) implies (B).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 1970, [Harry Kesten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Kesten) proposed essentially this question in the Advanced Problems section of *The American Math Monthly*.

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be iid random variables and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Show that
>   $$
> \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|X_n|}{|S_{n-1}|} = \infty \quad \text{with probability 1,}
> $$
>   whenever the $\mathbb E |X_i|$, the expectation of $|X_i|$ is infinite.

[The solution](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317542), also by Kesten, is in the March 1971 issue (*The American Math Monthly*, vol. 78, no. 3, 305–308). The proof relies on first reducing to the case where the $X_i$ take values in $\{2^k: k \in \mathbb N\}$.

He further uses it to prove a result of Chow and Robbins,

> If $\mathbb E|X_i| = \infty$ and $(b_n)$ is any sequence of positive numbers, then either
>   $\liminf_n |S_n|/b_n = 0$ almost surely or $\limsup_n |S_n|/b_n = \infty$ almost surely.